# Hadoop: Unable to allocate more than 8 GB Memory to my nodes

Tags: hadoop, memory

My hadoop setup was only allocating 8 GB of ememory to each node even tough my machines have 126GB ram and 32 CPU.

I added the following properties to my yarn-site.xml to allocate 24 GB memory to each node.

```
<property>
   <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>1024</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>2048</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>24576</value>
</property>
```

I also added following to the mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
  <value>32</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum</name>
  <value>16</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps</name>
  <value>0.95</value>
</property>
```

Now my nodes do show 24 GB each of allocated memory but when I run my task lot of reduce tasks start before the mappers are done and all tasks keep failing. Most of them fail with this exception:

```
15/04/09 19:24:45 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1428621766709_0001_m_000031_2, Status : FAILED
Exception from container-launch: org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException:
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException:
```

The same process used to run earlier with default configuration of 8 GB per node. It would take couple of hours to complete but used to work. Now I cant even get the process to run.

Any pointers here will be really helpful.

Comment: No use of configuring maximum maps or reduces in Yarn.. It just consider it as a task.

Comment: I removed the max maps and reduce configuration but that did not make any difference.

Comment: When  I remove all the above mentioned congifs I am able to run my process but now my nodes only get 8GB memory each so max 14 reducers which makes it very slow. Can any one provide me the details of how they changed the default memory availabe to each node